# How do I detect and/or delete empty Subversion directories?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have been searching on Google but couldn't find an answer for this. How can I detect and/or remove empty directories on a Subversion repository? I want to delete those directories; all they have in them is their .svn directory.

I am running Windows and have access to SVN on the command line and I also have TortoiseSVN installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you'll have to script somehow because there isn't a Subversion command to do this.  You could use "svn ls -R URL_TO_REPO_ROOT" and then get entries that end in / that do not have any children in them.  For "svn ls" a directory always ends with a "/" so use this to your advantage when scripting this.

Comment: beware though... its possible that some of those directories contain `svn:externals`... i would do this to a working copy instead of the REPO_URL... and then commit changes if i were you.

Comment: Good point.  In a working copy, you could also have empty directories due to the checkout/update depth which is why I suggested using a URL for the "svn ls -R" instead of a working copy path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that detects the empty directories in a working copy:

https://gist.github.com/852051

There are shorter solutions on [this page](http://jamesjava.blogspot.com/2007/09/remove-empty-subversion-directories.html) but they won't work recursively when a complete directory hierarchy is empty.